# Port-forwarding and port status

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, nat

I have a host behind a router (Thomson TWG870) with the two forwarding rules:

```
1. external: 0.0.0.0:22, internal: 192.168.0.10:22
2. external: 0.0.0.0:26, internal: 192.168.0.10:26
```

There is a ssh serer running on 192.168.0.10 on port 22. There is no application running on port 26. 
And here is my question. When i run online port scanner (http://www.ipfingerprints.com/portscan.php for e.g.) and check ports 22 & 26 it returns that port 22 is `open` (as expected) but the port 26 is stated as `filtered`. Should't it be stated as just `closed` since the port is open but no application running? How can it be configured to respond `closed`?

P.S.
When i test the port 27 (for e.g.) which isn't forwarded on the router i also get status `filtered`.

Comment: What OS is the host running?

Comment: The host is running Win 7.

Answer (score 1):

This is dependant on what the site is using to scan your external address.

If it's a SYN scan, for instance from nmap its defined as an "open" TCP port if a SYN packet sent by nmap gets an ACK packet from the target system.

Normally in scans when you see filtered, it's because the port is open , but only open to a specified ip or network range. You usually don't see this with "any or 0.0.0.0" rules.

You shouldn't be seeing a port as open if there is no target destination port-forwarded. (This is assuming the router isn't supplied by your ISP with ports open/filtered for their use.) Verizon is known to do this with actiontec routers to push firmware & VOD guide updates over their network.

Try scanning your network externally with nmap. Or try using other sites, like canyouseeme.org. and see if the scans match what you are seeing.

Comment: `Normally in scans when you see filtered, it's because the port is open , but only open to a specified ip or network range. You usually don't see this with "any or 0.0.0.0" rules` - do You mean that when there is 0.0.0.0 rule even if the port is not blocked by the firewall the status returned is filtered instead of closed?

Comment: No, I usually see it as the opposite. If I make a rule that only 108.245.12.121 can connect to port 22. When I scan my public IP externally, If no service is behind port 22 on a portforwarded machine, it comes up as closed. If there is a service running on 22 with the rule the scan comes up as filtered. I tried it briefly with a pfsense 2.x installation and a separate router before I posted that

Answer (score 0):

> Should't it be stated as just closed since the port is open but no application running?

Technically yes, but it depends on your OS – a few (such as Windows or FreeBSD) default to some kind of "stealth mode", in which ports without listeners don't trigger any response.

('Closed' is TCP RST or ICMP "Port Unreachable", while 'filtered' is no reply at all.)

For Windows, see the following articles:

- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd448557(WS.10)
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff720058.aspx

As documented in them, you should be able to disable stealth mode using:

```
reg add HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\PrivateProfile /v DisableStealthMode /t REG_DWORD /d 1
reg add HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\PublicProfile /v DisableStealthMode /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

For FreeBSD (e.g. pfSense), the equivalent sysctl options are `net.inet.tcp.blackhole=0` and `net.inet.udp.blackhole=0`.

> P.S. When i test the port 27 (for e.g.) which isn't forwarded on the router i also get status filtered.

In your router, packets to non-forwarded ports are treated as input (that is, received by the router itself). Again, the router's firewall will very often have a final rule which *discards* unknown packets instead of rejecting them.

Depending on router type, this *might* be configurable by adding a custom firewall rule which rejects unknown packets.